# Can Cisco ASA 5510 (or 5520) suppress its logging when under DOS attack?

Tags: logging

I know that Bluecoat devices for instance can suppress their logging under e.g. bad CPU circumstances like DOS attack.
Do other devices like (Cisco ASA) Firewalls protect themselves as well ?

Logging is not directly critical for the functioning of device itself, so I've always learned that devices suppress non-critical tasks like logging, when their CPU is running 100% due to whatever bad circumstances (DOS attack, flood of broadcast messages etc).

Comment: Yes, Cisco ASAs do this too.

Comment: This is a question for Cisco support.